# How to use RegEx.Replace to replace the . and - to a / on the following date string 01.04-2016

Tags: c#

I have the date string that was entered incorrectly that I need to correct and would like to know if I could use RegEx.Replace to achieve this.

date string on file is 01.10-2016

I would like to replace the "." and "-" with a "/"

Comment: This should capture the parts: [`(\d{2})\.(\d{2})-(\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/UadJTM/1)

Comment: Here's what I enter MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace("01.04-2016", @"(\d{2})\.(\d{2})-(\d{4})", "/")); but it returns just and "/"

Comment: Hi, is there anything you're still unsure about with this question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression: `(\d{2})\.(\d{2})-(\d{4})`

Breaking it down:

- `\d` - Matches numbers
- `{2}` and `{4}` - Expects the previous pattern (in our case `\d`) to appear 2 and 4 times respectively.
- `(  )` - Creates a capture group
- `\.` - `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions, so we'll escape it.
- `\.` and `-` are static values, that we expect to be between our capture groups.

So the parts are of our final expression:

- `(\d{2})` - Match and capture any two digit number from 00 to 99
- `\.` - Match a `.`
- `(\d{2})` - Match and capture any two digit number from 00 to 99
- `-` - Match a `-`
- `(\d{4})` - Match and capture any four digit number from 0000 to 9999

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/UadJTM/1)

Now, to actually format the date as you want, we need to take the data captured by these 3 capture groups and perform the replacement. You can reference them by their position in the regex, so we have `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`.

```
var input = "01.10-2016";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d{2})\.(\d{2})-(\d{4})", "$1/$2/$3");
```

This should output your desired values.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FGM5149)

Comment: This is what I was looking for - thanks for your assistance